# How does phonon scattering change the distribution function?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, simulations, equilibrium, phonons, density-of-states

For a one-dimensional structure, we know that the modified distribution function has the following energy dependency in equilibrium:
\begin{equation}
Z(\varepsilon)\,f(\varepsilon) = \dfrac{N_\text{1D}}{\sqrt{\varepsilon-E_\text{C}}}
\times \exp\left( -\dfrac{\varepsilon-E_\text{F}}{k_\text{B}T} \right)
\,\Theta(\varepsilon-E_\text{C})
\end{equation}
with $E_\text{C}$ being the conduction band minimum and $E_\text{F}$ the Fermi level.
$Z(\varepsilon)$ is the 1D density of states, and $f(\varepsilon)$ is the equilibrium distribution function (excluding the Pauli principle, of course).

How does the presence of elastic, inelastic, optical and acoustic phonon scattering mechanisms change the above mentioned distribution function? Do we expect to see sharp peaks and spikes in certain energies?

I would be thankful if you could also recommend references on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's answer the question: what part of that equation would change?

$f\left(\epsilon\right)$ is always the same if you're in equilibrium. Scattering won't change that, because scattering alone won't move you out of equilibrium. If anything, scattering has the opposite effect.

What can change is $Z\left(\epsilon\right)$. How it would change depends on your system, which you haven't really specified. That said, scattering mechanisms are usually assumed to be small perturbations on the known system. That's usually a good assumption, so unless you have a crazy system, I'd say that things aren't likely to change much.

*Electrons and Phonon* by J. M. Ziman is a classic text on the subject.